# Set predefined latitude and longitude in Mapbox instead of tap on location

Tags: swift, navigation, mapbox

I need help in figuring this out,
I integrated Mapbox Navigation in iOS app, all works perfect.

Except that the standard functionality of this SDK is that the user must tap on a spot on the map and navigation will start to that spot.

What I need is to remove this standard functionality and add in place of it a predefined latitude and longitude of a location, to set navigation to it automatically.

Here is the standard func for picking a location on the map and navigating to it:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add a gesture recognizer to the map view
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPress(_:)))
    }

@objc func didLongPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.state == .began else { return }

        // Converts point where user did a long press to map coordinates
        let point = sender.location(in: mapView)
       //
        let coordinate = mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

        // Create a basic point annotation and add it to the map
        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = "В Пути"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        // Calculate the route from the user's location to the set destination
        calculateRoute(from: (mapView.userLocation!.coordinate), to: annotation.coordinate) { (route, error) in
            if error != nil {
                Alert.showBasic(title: "Error!", message: "Error calculating route...", vc: self)
                print("Error calculating route")
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried changing the coordinate this way:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.returnedLatitude as! CLLocationDegrees, self.returnedLongitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
```

But it didn't work! Please help anyone who used this framework before.